# How to make coroutines launch next job only when first is finished

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Lets say that I have a button, which has a listener in Android:

```
someView.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.doSomething()
}
```

This will create a new Job for each time that the button is pressed. In my ViewModel, the doSomething function is launching suspend functions from the viewModelScope:

```
fun doSomething() {
  viewModelScope.launch {
       doSomething1()
       doSomething2()
       doSomething3() 
   }
}

suspend fun doSomething1() {
    delay(100)
    Log.d("TEST", "doSomething1: 1 ")
}

suspend fun doSomething2() {
    delay(300)
    Log.d("TEST", "doSomething2: 2 ")
}

fun doSomething3() {
    Log.d("TEST", "doSomething3: 3 ")
}
```

Now, if this button gets pressed very quickly in succession (in theory, lets say i can call the function from the listener twice, so that the execution of the first call hasn't finished yet), I will get following result in my logcat:

> ```
> D/TEST: doSomething1: 1
> D/TEST: doSomething1: 1
> D/TEST: doSomething2: 2
> D/TEST: doSomething3: 3
> D/TEST: doSomething2: 2
> D/TEST: doSomething3: 3
> ```

What I actually want to achieve is, what would happen if I could launch `doSomething()` twice from the same scope, so it runs synchronous.

> ```
> D/TEST: doSomething1: 1
> D/TEST: doSomething1: 2
> D/TEST: doSomething2: 3
> D/TEST: doSomething3: 1
> D/TEST: doSomething2: 2
> D/TEST: doSomething3: 3
> ```

How can I achieve that behaviour, so that before starting the same coroutine, the first one has to finish?

Comment: what if you press button three or more times, do you want to launch three and more coroutines one after another? Or maybe you don't want to launch another coroutine if the previous one hasn't been finished yet?

Comment: Yes @Sergey, no matter how many, they should wait for the previous one to finish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Mutex lock to do this - the lock would keep subsequent 1-2-3 sequences from launching until the prior ones are complete, no matter how many times you push the button.

```kotlin
private val lock = Mutex()

fun doSomething() {
  viewModelScope.launch {
       // lock means only one "1-2-3" sequence can execute 
       // at a time, subsequent calls will suspend here and wait
       // for the lock to be released before starting
       lock.withLock {
           doSomething1()
           doSomething2()
           doSomething3() 
       }
   }
}
```

You could also use a channel to run them one at a time

```kotlin
private val channel = Channel<Job>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED).apply {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        consumeEach { it.join() }
    }
}

fun doSomething() {
    channel.trySend(
        // send a lazily executed "1-2-3" job to the channel for it
        // to run (will run jobs one at a time and wait for each
        // job to complete before starting the next)
        viewModelScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            doSomething1()
            doSomething2()
            doSomething3() 
        } 
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by saving the last job and waiting for it to finish before executing a new coroutine:

```
private var lastJob: Job? = null

fun doSomething() {
    val prevJob = lastJob
    lastJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
        prevJob?.join()
        doSomething1()
        doSomething2()
        doSomething3()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it was still the result as if i didnt use the limited parallelism

Comment: @Igor please see my edited answer.

Comment: @Igor have you tried my approach? It should work as you expect.