# Execute coroutine (launch{}/Job) sequential order ( the order they called)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

How can I run multiple `coroutine` sequentially(like the order they were called ) inside a `coroutine`. I am creating multiple `coroutine` inside a `coroutine`, I want sequential execution as the order they are called.

Here is my sample code.

```
fun main(){
    runBlocking {
        Launch().run()
    }
}

class Launch {
     fun run(){
        for (i in 1..10){
            println("Starting $i")
            GlobalScope.launch {
                println("working id $i")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and output is

```
Starting 1
Starting 2
Starting 3
Starting 4
Starting 5
Starting 6
Starting 7
Starting 8
working id 5
working id 4
working id 3
Starting 9
working id 1
Starting 10
working id 2
working id 8
working id 7
working id 6
working id 9
working id 10
```

Inside the loop all `coroutine` are executing asynchronously, I know it's natural behavior of coroutine. But I want to execute all the coroutine sequentially how can I do that?

**Edit:**

**Its not duplicate**

[This question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480520/kotlin-coroutines-sequential-execution) does not answer my question.

> That answer works for one block execution at a time, but don't
> maintain order. I need to maintain execution order as like they called

Tried with suggested approach

```
fun main(){
    runBlocking {
       // Launch().run()
        Launch().complex()
        delay(1000)
        println("Finish")
    }
}

class Launch {
    private val lock = Mutex()

    private fun func(name:String) {
        println("method $name")
        GlobalScope.launch {
            lock.withLock {
                println("$name started")
                println("$name completed")
            }
        }
    }

    fun complex() {
        func("1")
        func("2")
        func("3")
        func("4")
        func("5")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
method 1
method 2
method 3
method 4
method 5
1 started
1 completed
3 started
3 completed
4 started
4 completed
2 started
2 completed
5 started
5 completed
Finish
```

Please check that after 1 completed, 3 is started but call order was `1,2,3,4,5`,  that means execution order  is not maintained as the called with `GlobalScope.launch`

I want to execute as the order they were called.

**Expected output :**

```
method 1
method 2
method 3
method 4
method 5
1 started
1 completed
2 started
2 completed
3 started
3 completed
4 started
4 completed
5 started
5 completed
Finish
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318010/how-to-make-coroutines-launch-next-job-only-when-first-is-finished/72319023#72319023) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480520/kotlin-coroutines-sequential-execution/63494023#63494023). You can use a Channel to do sequential coroutine execution like a queue.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked those, hoping is there any easy other approach available.

Comment: The answers to those questions cover pretty much all the available options - they really aren't that complicated. What's the problem with using a channel? That's basically what it's for, to act like a queue. Check its [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html) for more info.

Comment: Tried with `Mutex` not working. changed the `run` method with `lock.withLock { .. for loop here.. }`  but not working . Executing asynchronously

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Coroutines sequential execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480520/kotlin-coroutines-sequential-execution)

Comment: @sidgate no, tried that solution

Comment: I have added explanation why this question is not duplicate.

Comment: Using `Channel` with `launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY)` seems to be the key.

Comment: You can also use `Flow`s to solve the call order problem, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332468/1731626.

Comment: Using  `Mutex` is not guaranteed the order of execution.

Comment: Like we have said here at least three times now, use a channel if you need to guarantee order. Scroll down to the last example in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480520/kotlin-coroutines-sequential-execution/63494023#63494023), the one using a channel.

Comment: ok i will check